# Application of power series expansion

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, power-series

The following is a part of a proof.

Let $\phi(z) = 1 - \phi_1z - \phi_2z^2-\dots-\phi_qz^q$, such that $\phi(z) \neq 0$ when $|z| \leq 1$. This implies that there exists $\epsilon > 0$, such that
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\phi(z)} = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\pi_jz^j \qquad |z| < 1 + \epsilon. 
\end{equation}

Consequently, 
\begin{equation}
\pi_j(1+\epsilon/2)^j \rightarrow0
\end{equation}
as $j \rightarrow \infty$. So there exists a constant $K > 0$ for which
\begin{equation}
\pi_j < K (1 + \epsilon/2)^{-j},
\end{equation}
for $j = 0, 1, 2, \dots$

How can we say from the power series expansion that
\begin{equation}
\pi_j(1+\epsilon/2)^j \rightarrow0 \qquad j \rightarrow\infty.
\end{equation}

How can we say from the convergence that the following can be written for all $j = 0, 1, 2, \dots$
\begin{equation}
\pi_j < K (1 + \epsilon/2)^{-j}.
\end{equation}

Edit: A mathematical illustration of how these equations are obtained is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

For the first question, observe that for $\sum a_j$ to converge we must have $a_j \to 0$.

For the second question, observe that any convergent sequence must be bounded.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Make sense now.

Comment: Can you also explain why $(1 + \epsilon/2)$ is defined rather than $(1 + \epsilon)$

Comment: Because the series is known to converge for $|z|<(1+\epsilon)$. There's no guarantee of convergence for $|z| = 1+\epsilon$, so taking $1+\epsilon/2$ will do.

Comment: Thanks, and also do we need to assume that $\epsilon$ is sufficiently small as well. Is it correct to understand it like this. $|\pi_jz^j| \leq |\pi_j||z|^j < |\pi_j|(1+\epsilon/2)^j < K$

Comment: $\epsilon$ must be $>0$ because of properties of radii of convergence. It is not correct to write exactly what you've written unless you explicitly state state you've chosen $z$ with $|z| < (1+\epsilon/2)$

Comment: Yes $\epsilon > 0$. But I don't think it can take all positive values right? Isn't it a positive value which is close to zero?

Comment: That likely depends on the values of the $\phi_i$. That said, $\epsilon$ (the letter) is usually used to represent small positive quantities. Does it matter, though?

Comment: Because $\phi(z) \neq 0$ is defined when $|z| \leq 1$. So doesn't it mean $\phi(z) = 0$ when $|z| > 1$? That's why I thought $\epsilon$ to be a small positive value around zero.

Comment: No, it means that $\phi(z) = 0$ can happen only for $z$ with $|z|>1$. Contrast this with saying that $\phi(z) = 0$ for *all* $z$ with $|z|>1$. What matters is that there is *some* $\epsilon > 0$ with the properties described. It's okay to think of it as small, because if $\epsilon > 0$ works, any positive number less than $\epsilon$ also works in its stead. In other words, we don't know how large $\epsilon$ can be, but we know it can be as small as we require while still being positive.